# Finding derivatives using the quotient rule

Tags: calculus

I am attempting to find the derivative of $\frac{(v^3 -2v\sqrt v) } v$ using the quotient rule I set the problem up like this: $v(3v^2 - 3v^{1/2}) - (v^3 - 2v^{3/2})1$ and the denominator is $v^2$ which I do not think it important until the end. Anyways from that I get $ \frac {2v^3 - 2v^{3/2}}{ v^2} $.

This is not the answer my book is getting, I am sure I messed up something simple.

Comment: $(v(3v^2 - 3v^{1/2}) - (v^3 - 2v^{3/2})1)/v^2$ is correct, but it is not equal to $ \frac {2v^3 - 2v^{3/2}} v $.

Comment: Then I will do this step here, I have done it many times and got the same answer every time. Likely I am making a simple math error because I am so bad at math. Anyways the numerator should come out to $3v^3 - 3v^{3/2} - v^3 + 2v^{3/2} $ which gives $2v^3 -v^{3/2}$

Comment: Could you also post the answer from the book?

Comment: I am still getting $-v^{2/3}$

Comment: The book got $2v- ( 1/ \sqrt v) $

Comment: @Jordan: That's what your first (not simplified) answer is. And they might not have used the quotient rule to get it.

Comment: After dividing each term of $2v^3 - v^{3/2}$ by $v^2$, you do get $2v - (1/\sqrt{v})$.  By the way, your original post seems to have $\frac{2v^3 - 2v^{3/2}}{v^2}$, not the correct $\frac{2v^3 - v^{3/2}}{v^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your simplification, because your first steps were correct. But your simplification is close (not quite). In other words, $3-2$ is very often less than $2$.

Seeing the answer your book gave, I wanted to also point out that there isn't much reason to use the quotient rule here. $\frac{(v^3 -2v\sqrt v) } v = v^2 - 2\sqrt v$, which is easier to differentiate.

Of course, the quotient rule has its place.

Comment: That is what I was getting, must have mistyped it here. But the book is giving me a v^-1/2 and I am getting 3/2

Comment: @Jordan: then you should divide by $v^2$, and you see that your answer and the book's answer are the same.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Jordan: $\frac {2v^3 - v^{3/2}}{ v^2} = \frac{ 2v^3}{v^2} - \frac{v^{3/2}}{v^2} = ...$ - and you can finish from there?

Comment: $2v - v^1/2$ I think.

Comment: @Jordan: the second fraction is $\dfrac{v^{3/2}}{v^2}=v^{3/2-2}=v^{-1/2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\operatorname{d}\frac{v^3-2v\sqrt v}{v}}{\operatorname{d}v} 
&=\frac{v(3v^2-2\sqrt{v}-2\cdot\frac{v}{2\sqrt{v}})-(v^3-2v\sqrt{v})}{v^2}\\
&=\frac{3v^3-2v\sqrt{v}-\frac{v^2}{\sqrt{v}}-v^3+2v\sqrt{v}}{v^2}\\
&=\frac{v^2(2v-\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}})}{v^2}\\
&=2v-\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}
\end{align}$$

You can also argue that $v>0$ since it is under a square root, and in the denominator, therefore we can reduce the original function:

$$\frac{v^3-2v\sqrt v}{v}=v^2-2\sqrt{v}$$

From here it is very straight forward to derive and have the same result.